# Compilation Error after adding reference asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, dll

I have a problem adding reference to my asp.net website. When i add reference (install-Package MySql.Data) to my project and the dll file get placed in my bin file, my website stops working and shows me a Compilation Error. The error is showed on every page. (not only layout.master)

> Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this
>   request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.
>
> Compiler Error Message: : at System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor
>   (System.String assemblyName) [0x00000] in :0
>
> /layout.master
>
> dmcs /target:library /lib:"/home/www/domainname.nl/Bin" /debug-
>   /optimize+ /warn:4
>   /out:"/home/tmp/mono/www.domainname.nl/1076622-temp-aspnet-0/4e6b8fd9/App_Web_layout.master.eb7fdfd9.710a6885.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.CSharp/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll" /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Services/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll" /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.EnterpriseServices/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.IdentityModel/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Runtime.Serialization/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Xaml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel.Web/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Extensions/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.DynamicData/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Data.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.Linq.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.ApplicationServices/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/gac/System.Security/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll"
>   /r:"/home/www/domainname.nl/Bin/MySql.Data.dll"  /nowarn:0169  --
>   "/home/tmp/mono/www.domainname.nl/1076622-temp-aspnet-0/4e6b8fd9/App_Web_layout.master.eb7fdfd9.710a6885_0.cs"
>   "/home/tmp/mono/www.domainname.nl/1076622-temp-aspnet-0/4e6b8fd9/App_Web_layout.master.eb7fdfd9.710a6885_1.cs"
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: The assembly name is
>   invalid.   at System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor (System.String
>   assemblyName) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ImportedAssemblyDefinition.ReadAttributes () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.MetadataImporter.GetAssemblyDefinition
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ReflectionImporter.ImportAssembly
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace
>   targetNamespace) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.DynamicLoader.LoadReferences (Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer
>   module) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
>   in :0  [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   The assembly name is invalid.   at
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor (System.String assemblyName)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ImportedAssemblyDefinition.ReadAttributes () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.CSharp.MetadataImporter.GetAssemblyDefinition
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.ReflectionImporter.ImportAssembly
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace
>   targetNamespace) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.CSharp.DynamicLoader.LoadReferences (Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer
>   module) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
>   in :0

Comment: are you using Mono 2.10.4?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using Mono 2.10.4 from the compiler error

```
App_Web_layout.master.eb7fdfd9.710a6885.dll" /r:"/usr/local/mono-2.10.4/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll"
```

I had the very same problem.

```
I upgraded from Mono 2.10.4 to 2.10.5 and the problem resolved itself.
```

Hope this helps you. Happy Coding !!

Comment: If i am right this is installed on the server? My host installed everything and i have no permissions to change these software

Comment: I have not combed the Mono class loader to understand why. I found this problem to be particularly irritating because the exception never tells you *why* the assembly name is invalid.